# Toggle arrow for jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tabs, toggle

I have looked everywhere and cannot figure this out. I basically have set up some custom jquery tabs, here is the javascript and fiddle I have for it, Im guessing I need to add to it?

```
    $(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs({
   collapsible: true,
   hide: 'slideUp', show: 'slideDown',
   active: false
});   
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/benopp/jadpcdvr/3/

If you look at the fiddle, I basically need the arrow to point up when any section of the tab is clicked, the same way a accordion toggle works, the arrow points down and when clicked to point back up. (I need it so the whole tab will trigger it, not just the arrow will trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the beforeActivate event on the tabs widget to detect when tabs are changing.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate

Then Set all arrows to down, see if any tabs are expanded, set its arrow to up:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    hide: 'slideUp',
    show: 'slideDown',
    active: false,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        //first set all arrows down:
        $("#tabs .arrow img").prop("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/White_Arrow_Down.svg");
        console.log(ui);
        if (ui.newTab.length > 0){
            ui.newTab.find(".arrow img").prop("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/White_Arrow_Up.svg");
        }
    }
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jadpcdvr/5/)**